# Identity proving

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can you help me prove this identity: $\tan x\sin x = \sec x-\csc x$?
I began working on the left side, by first changing $\tan x$ to $\sin x/\cos x$ and then multiplying by $\sin x$, I can get it down to $\sec x - \cos x$ but I can't figure out how to change the $\cos x$ to $\csc x$.

Comment: This identity is false : evaluate it at $\pi/4$ and you get $1/\sqrt{2} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Graph]

Red is tan(x)*sin(x) and blue is sec(x)-csc(x). As you can see, there are multiple places where this identity is false.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: if the expression equals sec(x)-cos(x), and it also were to equal sec(x)-csc(x), then sec(x)-cos(x)=sec(x)-csc(x), and then cos(x)=csc(x) is an identity, which is obviously false.